# How to use "not between" in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder, negation

I want to query not between in cakephp 3.x

I can use between like this. But I can't use not between.

```
array(function ($exp) use ($field_value, $txtRule1, $txtRule2) {
    return $exp->between($field_value, $txtRule1, $txtRule2);
});
```

Any one have idea about how to use not between in cakephp 3.x

Thanks and Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it in `QueryExpression::not()`:

```
use \Cake\Database\Expression\BetweenExpression;
use \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression;

// ...

function (QueryExpression $exp) use ($field_value, $txtRule1, $txtRule2) {
    return
        $exp->not(
            new BetweenExpression(
                $field_value,
                $txtRule1,
                $txtRule2,
                $exp->typeMap()->type($field_value)
            )
        );
}
```

The new expression instance is required as you'd otherwise nest the expression in itself, which would cause an infinite loop at some point. You could also use cloning in case you are sure that you are working with an empty expression instance

```
function (QueryExpression $exp) use ($field_value, $txtRule1, $txtRule2) {
    $between = clone $exp;
    return
        $exp->not(
            $between->between($field_value, $txtRule1, $txtRule2)
        );
}
```

or pass the query instance to the callable and create a new query expression instance

```
function (QueryExpression $exp) use ($field_value, $txtRule1, $txtRule2, $query) {
    return
        $exp->not(
            $query->newExpr()->between($field_value, $txtRule1, $txtRule2)
        );
}
```

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression::not()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Database.Expression.QueryExpression.html#_not)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::newExpr()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_newExpr)**